# Angular 2 how to bubble up an event from a nested component

Tags: angular

I have:

```
<modal
  #forgotPasswordModal
  [viewModel]="forgotPasswordModalVm"
  (cancelled)="onForgotPasswordModalCancelled($event)"
  (saved)="onForgotPasswordModalSaved($event)">
  <forgot-password></forgot-password>
</modal>
```

Once the forgot password form is complete, I need it to close the modal by calling close() on the parent modal component above. I can fire an event with the EventEmitter, but how can I receive it on the parent container? I don't want any forgot-password specific log inside the modal component, nor do I want to use a generic event service.

Comment: What's wrong with, i.e. `(close)="onModalClose($event)"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<modal
  #forgotPasswordModal
  [viewModel]="forgotPasswordModalVm"
  (cancelled)="onForgotPasswordModalCancelled($event)"
  (saved)="onForgotPasswordModalSaved($event)">
  <forgot-password (close)="onModalClose()"></forgot-password>
</modal>
```

```
export class ForgotPasswordComponent {
  @Output() close:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  // execute when the modal should be closed
  onComplete() {
    this.close.emit(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! However, it called onModalClose() on the parent component of modal, (not modal), so I just changed it to (close)="forgotPasswordModal.onModalClose()" and that worked.